# What must be true in order to sort objects?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

So my title is my question... What is the basic requirement or what must be true in order to sort objects?
 Here are some of the choices:

A. They must be wrapper classes of primitives (Integer, Double, etc.)

B. They must be Comparable.

C. At least one instance variable must be a primitive.

D. They must be Strings

E. Objects are not sortable, only primitives are sortable.

Comment: B. They must be Comparable.

Comment: None of the above. Even if they're not `Comparable`, you can sort them using a `Comparator`.

Comment: Did you try to make some Java program in order to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You sort can also sort arrays of primitives using the standard library methods. And the question doesn't say "using the provided / standard library"; you can sort anything provided you write the code to do it. Agree, none of the answers is correct.

Answer (score 1):

B. Comparable.

A quick search in the [java documentation for Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) reveals:

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's natural ordering, and the class's compareTo method is referred to as its natural comparison method.
>
> Lists (and arrays) of objects that implement this interface can be sorted automatically by Collections.sort (and Arrays.sort). Objects that implement this interface can be used as keys in a sorted map or as elements in a sorted set, without the need to specify a comparator.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of sorting objects in Java. They should either be [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (of the same type! both `Integer`s and `String`s are comparable, but you can't just sort a list that contains both out of the box), or you should use an explicit [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) of the right type.

Comment: Or, if you like reinventing the wheel, you write a custom sort routine which inherently understands the specific objects to be sorted and can only sort those kinds of objects...